# How do I fix this Python Tic-Tac-Toe code error

Tags: python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

I am new to python and tried to make tic-tac-toe as a challenge. I keep getting this error in which the computer gets two spaces as O and says that it won even though it has one more space to capture. Please help and make changes to the code as necessary.

*The code:*

```
board = ["_"] * 9

print('0' + '|' + '1' + '|' + '2')
print('3' + '|' + '4' + '|' + '5')
print('6' + '|' + '7' + '|' + '8')

print(" ")

def foo():
    print(board[0] + '|' + board[1] + '|' + board[2])
    print(board[3] + '|' + board[4] + '|' + board[5])
    print(board[6] + '|' + board[7] + '|' + board[8])

foo()

for spaces in board:
    from random import randint

    winning0 = board[0] and board[1] and board[2]
    winning1 = board[3] and board[4] and board[5]
    winning2 = board[6] and board[7] and board[8]
    winning3 = board[0] and board[3] and board[6]
    winning4 = board[1] and board[4] and board[7]
    winning5 = board[2] and board[5] and board[8]
    winning6 = board[0] and board[4] and board[8]
    winning7 = board[2] and board[4] and board[6]

    player = int(input("Player 1 choose a number between 0-8: "))
    print(" ")
    board[player] = "X"
    foo()
    print(" ")
```

Is there a way I can make this part shorter because it is very repetitive.

```
  if board[player] == winning0:
    print("Player 1 won!")
    break

  if board[player] == winning1:
    print("Player 1 won!")
    break

  if board[player] == winning2:
    print("Player 1 won!")
    break

  if board[player] == winning3:
    print("Player 1 won!")
    break

  if board[player] == winning4:
    print("Player 1 won!")
    break

  if board[player] == winning5:
    print("Player 1 won!")
    break 

  if board[player] == winning6:
    print("Player 1 won!")
    break

  if board[player] == winning7:
    print("Player 1 won!")
    break

  computer = randint(0, 8)
  new = randint(0, 8)
  new1 = randint(0, 8)

  if int(computer) == int(player):  
    computer.replace(computer,new)
    print('The computer choose ' + '%s' % computer)
    board[computer] = "O"

  elif int(computer) != int(player):
    print('The computer choose ' + '%s' % computer)
    board[computer] = "O"

  elif int(computer) == int(computer):  
    computer.replace(computer,new1)
    print('The computer choose ' + '%s' % computer)
    board[computer] = "O"

  foo()
  print(" ")

  if board[computer] == winning0:
    print("The computer won!")
    break

  if board[computer] == winning1:
    print("The computer won!")
    break

  if board[computer] == winning2:
    print("The computer won!")
    break

  if board[computer] == winning3:
    print("The computer won!")
    break

  if board[computer] == winning4:
    print("The computer won!")
    break

  if board[computer] == winning5:
    print("The computer won!")
    break

  if board[computer] == winning6:
    print("The computer won!")
    break

  if board[computer] == winning7:
    print("The computer won!")
    break
```

This is the numbering system.

```
0|1|2
3|4|5
6|7|8
```

This is the error.

```
Player 1 choose a number between 0-8: 1

X|X|_
_|_|_
O|_|_

The computer choose 2
X|X|O
_|_|_
O|_|_

The computer won!
```

Answer (score 0):

To shorten the code:

```
    print("Player 1 won!")
    break

  if board[player] == winning1:
    print("Player 1 won!")
    break

  if board[player] == winning2:
    print("Player 1 won!")
    break

  if board[player] == winning3:
    print("Player 1 won!")
    break

  if board[player] == winning4:
    print("Player 1 won!")
    break

  if board[player] == winning5:
    print("Player 1 won!")
    break 

  if board[player] == winning6:
    print("Player 1 won!")
    break

  if board[player] == winning7:
    print("Player 1 won!")
    break
```

You could shorten it by making it one statement, like this:

```
if board[player] == winning1 or board[player] == winning2 or board[player] == winning3 or board[player] == winning4 or board[player] == winning5 or board[player] == winning6 or board[player] == winning7:
    print("Player 1 won!")
    break
```

this line is more than 120 characters, I don't know if this will effect your program, otherwise you could cut it into two 'if' statements

The same can be applied for the computer winning

And! I'm not sure, but I think you could leave the break. If the 'if' statement is satisfied it will automaticity go to the next line. If you make it one statement like I did. You shouldn't need to use the break.

Also! If there are only two outcomes (player wins and computer wins) you can replace the computer 'if' with an 'else' statement reducing the amount of variables that need to be checked.

-JL

Comment: This is helpful for shortening the code, but I still don't understand the error with the computer winning. Please help.

Comment: The whole code is under the heading: The code. So I don't have a .py file.

Comment: The post under mine is right. if you don't want to rewrite your code, you should fill in all the empty variables so that you can help the problem. But! You should look at another approach, so you can make your code better and to gain insight.

Answer (score 0):

```
winning0 = board[0] and board[1] and board[2]
```

All non-empty string are True. Therefore this `and` sequence will return the last element. Test this in your console and see: `print('_' and '_' and '_')`.

```
if board[player] == winning0:
```

This basically means if character at player's position equals to `_` (because all winningN are equal to `'_'` as explained above).

> The computer won!

Your "what if computer takes the already taken place" approach is so strange that one of the `if`s gets triggered even though it should always compare just-put character (so X or O) to winningN (so _)...

---

How to fix this?

Re-do the whole program. Seriously. It's a completely wrong approach - `winningN` variables don't make much sense, `if`s make little sense, seeing how `winning` variables behave...

Tips:

After every move compare lines to the current sign - probably use a function to keep the code cleaner. And yes, that means `winning` stuff needs to be re-calculated every time, they are not dynamic, in your code they will always equal to `'_'` no matter what.

Also, use list for your `winning`, instead of making multiple variables. ;) When the elements are created correctly (with comparing to current sign), checking if any of the lines are winning can be shortened a lot.